# Ruby: Rspec 2.14.1 on ruby 1.9.1 compatibility

Tags: ruby, rspec

Before anything, I know 1.9.1 (1.9.1-p243 specifically) is old and broken, but we have an app with a pretty strict dependency on it.

First off, is there a list of rspec-supported rubies?

Secondly, when putting anything in a describe block in a spec, I get an error `uninitialized constant BasicObject::Class (NameError)`.

With this spec:

```
require_relative 'rspec_basic_object_test'

describe RspecBasicObjectTest do
  before :each do
    @obj = RspecBasicObjectTest.new
  end
  it 'returns something' do
    @obj.foo.should == "foo"
  end
end
```

and this ruby file:

```
class RspecBasicObjectTest
  attr_reader :foo

  def initialize
    @foo = "foo"
  end
end
```

I get:

```
dlampa@ubuntu:~/code/mine$ rspec rspec_basic_object_test_spec.rb 
/home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-mocks-2.14.6/lib/rspec/mocks/syntax.rb:74:in `block in enable_should': uninitialized constant BasicObject::Class (NameError)
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-mocks-2.14.6/lib/rspec/mocks/syntax.rb:28:in `class_eval'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-mocks-2.14.6/lib/rspec/mocks/syntax.rb:28:in `enable_should'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-mocks-2.14.6/lib/rspec/mocks/configuration.rb:34:in `syntax='
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-mocks-2.14.6/lib/rspec/mocks/configuration.rb:52:in `<module:Mocks>'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-mocks-2.14.6/lib/rspec/mocks/configuration.rb:2:in `<module:RSpec>'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-mocks-2.14.6/lib/rspec/mocks/configuration.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p243/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p243/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-mocks-2.14.6/lib/rspec/mocks/framework.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p243/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p243/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-mocks-2.14.6/lib/rspec/mocks.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p243/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p243/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/mocking/with_rspec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p243/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p243/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:388:in `mock_with'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:278:in `mock_framework'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:884:in `configure_mock_framework'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:280:in `ensure_example_groups_are_configured'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:295:in `set_it_up'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:245:in `subclass'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:232:in `describe'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:18:in `describe'
from /home/dlampa/code/mine/rspec_basic_object_test_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
from /home/dlampa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p243@rspec-test/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Anyone else run into this? Or am I just missing something obvious in rspec's README that says 1.9.1 is old and broken, why are you using it?

Comment: Supposedly rspec works on 1.8.6 or higher ([link](https://relishapp.com/rspec/docs/gettingstarted)).

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282389/rspec-mocks-raises-uninitialized-constant-basicobjectrspec

Comment: Both of you were very helpful. I can't decide if this is a bug in rspec that I should submit or if I should apply the "patch" mentioned in the latter link. Thoughts?